# GROUP BY column and clause in postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I would like group the columns of a table with by a column value as well as when another condition is met. For example, with the following table:

Events:

```
id  session_id  flags        created_at  ...
--------------------------------------------
1   100         OTHER        ...
2   101         OTHER        ...
3   101         NEW_SESSION  ...
4   101         OTHER        ...
5   101         NEW_SESSION  ...  
6   100         OTHER        ...
7   102         OTHER        ...
```

I want the following result:

```
session_id  events_count first_event_id  last_event_id  
-------------------------------------------------------
100-0       2            1               6
101-0       1            2               2
101-1       2            3               4
101-2       1            5               5
102-0       1            7               7
```

The basic idea is that I want to extract sessions from events. They are grouped by session_id. I also want a new session whenever I have the flag `NEW_SESSION`.

The query is something like this:

```
SELECT ? as session_id
  , count(id) as events_count
  , MIN(id) as first_event_id
  , MAX(id) last_event_id
GROUP BY session_id
  -- , and whenever flags is NEW_SESSION
ORDER BY id
```

But I dont know how to express the group by condition properly. Any idea ?

Comment: What's the logic behind 101-0 and 101-1?

Comment: @JakubKania `101` is the original session id, and `0`, `1`, `2` is an increment so that we can "cut" sessions and still have unique session ids. Because session 101 has two `NEW_SESSION` flags, I want to cut this session into 3 chunks.

Comment: I ended up achieving this with window functions inside CTEs. A first window with lag, and another with sum, both `PARTITION`ing  on session_id

Comment: You may want to post it an an answer for others to see then.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

In the comments I've noticed that you want them unique. Then we can use a variable:

```sql
SET @inc := 0;

(
  SELECT CONCAT(session_id, '-', !ABS(STRCMP(flags, 'NEW_SESSION'))) AS session_id
  , COUNT(id) AS events_count
  , MIN(id) AS first_event_id
  , MAX(id) last_event_id
  FROM events
  WHERE flags != 'NEW_SESSION'
  GROUP BY events.session_id, events.flags
  ORDER BY events.id
) UNION (
  SELECT CONCAT(session_id, '-', @inc := @inc + 1) AS session_id
  , COUNT(id) AS events_count
  , MIN(id) AS first_event_id
  , MAX(id) last_event_id
  FROM events
  WHERE flags = 'NEW_SESSION'
  GROUP by events.id
  ORDER BY events.id
);
```

**Update**

The following prevents grouping for the `NEW_SESSION` rows:

```sql
(
  SELECT CONCAT(session_id, '-', !ABS(STRCMP(flags, 'NEW_SESSION'))) AS session_id
  , COUNT(id) AS events_count
  , MIN(id) AS first_event_id
  , MAX(id) last_event_id
  FROM events
  WHERE flags != 'NEW_SESSION'
  GROUP BY events.session_id, events.flags
  ORDER BY events.id
) UNION (
  SELECT CONCAT(session_id, '-1') AS session_id
  , COUNT(id) AS events_count
  , MIN(id) AS first_event_id
  , MAX(id) last_event_id
  FROM events
  WHERE flags = 'NEW_SESSION'
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY events.id
);
```

**Original answer**

As far as I understand, you are trying to group events by the session IDs and
"whether it's a NEW_SESSION" flag. If it's so, then I'd express it as follows:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(session_id, '-', !ABS(STRCMP(flags, 'NEW_SESSION'))) AS session_id
, COUNT(id) AS events_count
, MIN(id) AS first_event_id
, MAX(id) last_event_id
FROM events
GROUP BY events.session_id, events.flags
ORDER BY events.id;
```

Comment: There could be many different `NEW_SESSION` flags, resulting in as many new sessions. I've updated my question to reflect that.